# .net application in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a requirement where I have to create a new .net web applictaion and Iframe it on the sharepoint site.

We would like to do this beacause users losing access to this application when the sharepoint server goes down and the idea is to build a seperate .net application and iframe it on sharepoint so users can access the application even when the server goes down.

I am very new to this and I am not sure how to IFrame the application on sharepoint and also please let me know how to implement security if i IFrame it.

If there is any better solution please let me know...

Thanks.

Comment: Actually SharePoint itself is a .NET application and you can build webparts in ASP.NET and use them in SharePoint. You should actually solve the problem of improving the server uptime, because your "iframed" app could as well go down.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the Page Viewer Web Part. Or you can also use a content editor web part and insert your html code directly.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/page-viewer-web-part-HA010024045.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. But How about security permissions? Can we setup permissions on the sharepoint side? I read somewhere that IFrame uses windows Authentication and we cannot make use of sharepoint permissions here. is this true?

Comment: Well technically it's very similar to just another browser window. If your remote URL uses integrated authentication it will try to authenticate with the current user.